# Getting Xcode to drop "No XXX method found" warning when delegating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

This could be me doing the design pattern wrong.

I'm implementing asynchronous delegation in an application that uses `NSURLConnection`. An object wraps the `NSURLConnection` and handles its delegated messages; that works fine. Now I'm defining my own delegates in the object that uses it (`NSURLConnection` messages `ConnectionWrapper`, `ConnectionWrapper` messages `NeedsToUseConnection`, you get the idea), and that works as well, however, Xcode emits this warning:

***No '-request:finishedWithResult' method found***

This is, presumably, because I'm declaring the delegate I'm calling like this:

```
id<NSObject> delegate;
```

...and Xcode is checking what `NSObject` declares in the Foundation framework. My custom delegate message is not there.  I am properly insulating the call:

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithResult:)])
    [delegate request:self finishedWithResult:ret];
```

Aside from turning the warning off -- I like to work with as many warnings on as possible -- is there a way to communicate (either syntactically or via a compiler directive) that I am aware this message is undeclared?  Should I, instead, be using an interface design pattern for this á la Java?  Using `id<WillReceiveRequestMessages>` or something?

Open to suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A better way of doing it would be to create your own delegate protocol:

```
@protocol MyControlDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)request:(MyControl *)request didFinishWithResult:(id)result;

@end
```

Then, you would declare your delegate like this:

```
id <MyControlDelegate> delegate;
```

The compiler will no longer complain when you write this:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didFinishWithResult:)])
    [delegate request:self didFinishWithResult:result];
```

The `<NSObject>` syntax is important in the protocol definition because it tells the compiler to incorporate the `NSObject` protocol. This is how your protocol gets methods like `respondsToSelector:`. If you left that out, the compiler would start complaining about `respondsToSelector:` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I just saw an example of that with UIAlertViewDelegate, and that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> This is, presumably, because I'm declaring the delegate I'm calling
>   like this: ...and Xcode is checking what NSObject declares in the
>   Foundation framework.

That is incorrect. If that were the case then you would get a warning about the object "may not respond to" the method, or something like that. This is a completely separate problem.

This warning is due to the fact that the compiler must know the signature of a selector in order to call it. This is because, behind the scenes, the compiler translates a method call to either `objc_msgSend` or `objc_msgSend_stret` depending on whether the method returns a `struct` type or not. If it doesn't know the return type, it will guess that it is not a `struct`, and use the first function. However, this could be wrong.

The solution is to have the method declared *anywhere* at all. It doesn't even have to be declared in the right class. You can declare it in some dummy protocol that is never used. So long as it is declared *somewhere*, the compiler will know and will be able to correctly compile it.